# Keep static HTML Element center on screen (under another scrollable div) by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three div a, b, c, all of them have "position: static" in there style (which is the default value for CSS position). They are all under the parent div, which is scrollable (CSS: "overflow-y: scroll").

```
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="div-a">...</div>
  <div id="div-b"><input id="my-input"></div> 
  <div id="div-c">...</div>
</div>
```

Div-a's height constantly change (for example, there are new children divs constantly appended under div-a). Normally, when div-a's height increase, div-b will be scrolled down.
I want to always keep the div-b at the center of the screen, no matter how div-a change in height
Is this possible in Javascript (or CSS, or both) ?

PS: I don't wanna use the CSS "position: fixed/sticky" because it's not possible in my project.

Comment: I want to do this with CSS but not using the applicable CSS rule?

Comment: Why can't you use position `sticky` or `fixed`?

Comment: Just an exception of using position: fixed/sticky, all other solution may be acceptable.

Comment: Because my project is an the existing social platform, my customer want to keep the input of the reply section fixed at the center of the screen, while other replies may come up under the article real-time.

Answer (score 0):

It's practically impossible to answer your question, because you haven't added enough detail to your question. How is div-b in the center of the screen at the minute, because what you've posted doesn't seem to illustrate how it would be positioned there. Anyway, I've somewhat guessed at your setup. If you don't want to use sticky or fixed, you are left with the only remaining potential solution, to set the parent to relative, and use position absolute to position the div.

```css
#parent-div {
overflow-y: scroll;
position:relative;
}

#div-a {
  
  height: 400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

#div-b {
position:absolute;
top:0;
}

#div-c {
position:static;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="div-a">div a</div>
  <div id="div-b"><input id="my-input"></div> 
  <div id="div-c">div c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely if I can design my project form the beginning days, I may use your CSS, but my project is an the existing social platform, my customer want to keep the input of the reply section fixed at the center of the screen, while other replies may come up under the article real-time. Using fixed position if not possible unfortunately, as it will break the existing design.

Comment: well, can I suggest you illustrate better in your question what the scope of the social platform is. Is there a link you can share to the problem etc. ? Can you create a minimum reproducible example. At the moment, you've a lump of HTML on the question, and not much context about how its working / not working currently, and where the 'design breaks' at the moment.